# Excel VBA prevent from importing missing references

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a sheet on Excel 2016, but when I want my collegues to test it on their machine which runs on Excel 2013, it throws error :

> "Can't find project or library error"

I know you can easily get rid of this error by going in Tools->References and uncheking the "MISSING" library.

But the problem is it's too complicated when you have too many people that don't necessarily know what VBA is and that get pissed off when asking them to follow a simplistic tutorial.

Is there a trick to get rid of all missing references at the start?

[image: This is an illustration from cpearson's site.]

Comment: Do they actually have the library installed? If so, just switch the late binding. If they don't have it installed, isn't the missing reference just going to give them *runtime* errors?

Comment: No when they uncheck it, it works fine there are no errors left. does that mean I have to declare all my variables as Object?

Comment: If it doesn't do anything in your code, why do you make use of it in the first place?

Comment: If it's not used you just can remove the link in your file and distribute it.

Comment: I only import libraries that cannot be unchecked. I do not know which one triggers the problem (Might be Microsoft Excel 2016), but I think VBA reimports the working one according to the version of Excel, once you uncheck the missing one, that's why it runs perfectly at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

However, you will open up a host of new problems since you'll need one more reference to the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility" (to access the `VBIDE` objects) and you'll need to have the security settings to enable "Trust Access To Visual Basic Project" (which is disabled by default, for good reasons).

That being said:
If you abide by those two criteria, you can run the following routine to remove any broken references from the active workbook:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveReferences()
    Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
    Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim chkRef As VBIDE.Reference

    Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE
    Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

    For Each chkRef In vbProj.References
        If chkRef.IsBroken Then
            vbProj.References.Remove chkRef
        End If
    Next

    Set vbProj = Nothing
    Set VBAEditor = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! I already came across something like this, but the problem as you said, is that it needs another alteration on my colleague's machine which they would not appreciate to do...

Comment: Well, it's the (only) solution to the problem as posed in the question. The problem here is that you're after doing something that has restrictions imposed on it (again: For good reasons).

If it's an option, switch to the full VS, and build your solution as an add-in in vb.net or C#.

Alternatively, educate your colleagues as to *why* these alterations are needed.