# Removing Missing References from Excel Workbook using VBA

Tags: python, vba, reference, runtime-error, missing-features

**ISSUE:**

Is there a way to remove missing references (references that have prefix: "MISSING" mentioned before their name) from an Excel workbook using VBA? I have a macro-enabled Excel workbook which I have to share with my colleagues from time to time. The workbook uses a special add-in that utilizes specific references. However, due to a limited number of licenses, not everyone has that add-in installed in their Excel, which is why the references associated with that add-in show up as "MISSING" in their workbooks and throw compilation errors when they try to run any macro. I don't want my collegues to go poking around the developer tab and uncheck the "MISSING" references each time they get the file. Is there a way this can be automated using VBA?

[Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg4yo.png)

**STEPS TAKEN ALREADY:**

- I already tried the following code but it didn't work.

Option Explicit

Sub References_RemoveMissing()

```
Dim theRef As Variant, i As Long         
For i = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set theRef = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i)
    If theRef.IsBroken = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

When I ran the above code, I got an error on line:

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef

The error stated: "Run-time error '-2147319779 (8002801d)': Object library not registered"

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1tGW.png)

- Before running the above code, I made sure that "Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility 5.3" is checkmarked/ticked in my MS Excel reference list and placed above the missing references (which I did by increasing its priority).
- My excel security settings were also set to "Trust Access To Visual Basic Project".

I looked up on google, this seems to be a pretty old issue. I found a bunch of old links suggesting the same coding solution but none of them seem to work for me.

[Excel VBA prevent from importing missing references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167070/excel-vba-prevent-from-importing-missing-references) (didn't work for me)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-check-and-remove-incorrect-project-references-in-the-visual-basic-editor-in-word-7ba187a6-9dfd-1288-8f08-d1f01ea02a3f (didn't work for me)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b90ed5cc-6bd1-46b4-bbea-de4a15521b26/detect-and-remove-missing-references-in-vba-code?forum=exceldev (didn't work for me)

**POSSIBLE ALTERNATE SOLUTION:**

If the missing references cannot be removed using VBA, is it possible to have an external Python-based script embedded within excel VBA that runs and removes the "MISSING" references?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: I have a similar problem (use of a specific add-in on a remote desktop adds a reference to the add-in to any Excel file used there).  We got around it by creating a dummy add-in of the same name which was enough to prevent the "missing reference" problem, and had the affected users install it in their Excel environment.  Kind of a pain but easier than having to process individual workbooks to remove the reference.

Comment: Can you guide me a bit regarding the process of creating a dummy add-in? 
How much of the code/features of the dummy add-in has to match the original add-in? Did you use any particular software/programming language to create the dummy add-in? 
Is there a link/website which shows how to implement this?

Comment: I created a standard .xlam (since that was what I was trying to mimic) and saved it with the same name.  There's no code inside other than a single "dummy" sub in a regular code module `Sub NotASub22():
    Debug.Print "Not a sub22!":
End Sub`  I don't think it matters what's in there, since it's never going to get called...

Comment: Did you also create dummy files for the references that were missing? i.e. dummy .exe or .dll files?

Comment: No my add-in only had xla-type files

Comment: So you didn't have to create any dummy reference .xla files, just a dummy add-in .xlam file, and have the users  add that add-in into their excel, right?

Comment: I just checked and they're xla not xlam - it's a pretty old add-in...   Then just follow the regular process for adding them as add-ins.

Comment: So, I tried the approach you suggested. I created a dummy .xla file by the name of "Risk". I then opened a blank document & loaded the dummy add-in into my excel application from File->Options->Add-Ins->Manage.  Saved document & closed it after adding add-in. 

Opened Excel workbook from the other computer containing the actual software. After opening, I still received compilation errors. Checked the references under tools in the Developer window. The same references were still marked as missing, eventhough the dummy "Risk" add-in is showing as active in the file.

Comment: I made sure that the name of the dummy matches the name of the .xla file associated with the actual add-in. Please let me know if I missed anything.

 As an additional step, I also copied the reference files from the computer containing the add-in and copied them onto the  PC where they were showing up as missing. This also did not work.

Comment: Sorry it sounds like your situation may be more complicated than mine.  I only had two .xla's to add; no DLL or exe files.